# Redirect second domain name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have the following .htaccess file which works fine for say www.companyone.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I also have the domain www.companytwo.com which points to the same site, i.e. www.companyone.com.  The problem is that when someone uses www.companytwo.com which correctly goes to the original website, the url still contains www.companytwo.com, when it should become www.companyone.com.

So in effect, I am ending up with 2 duplicate sites which is bad for seo.  Using the above .htaccess file, I am already ensuring that if a user types companyone.com, they automatically get redirected to www.companyone.com.  I need the same thing for www.companytwo.com, i.e. companytwo.com and www.companytwo.com should become www.companyone.com.

Is this something I need to fix via the .htaccess file or some virtual server file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the Browser to your www.companyone.com site by using .htacces:

```
# Redirect to www.companyone.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^companytwo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^companyone.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.companytwo.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.companyone.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# If your example works, this rewrite to index.php/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: How do I integrate that into my existing .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't understand, companyone and companytwo have the same root, same server, same website, so they will have to have the same .htaccess file.  So basically, I think I need to change companyone's .htaccess file to accomodate companytwo too.  Which was why I asked how to integrate your suggestion in to my current .htaccess file.

Comment: Well i missunderstood you, i thought there were 2 webroots. Test my solution now, this should work. Wait: You also redirect to index.php?.. I missed that. I will have a proper solution in a couple of minutes

Comment: If your current rewrite works, this works too. Put this together in one file. Tell me if this works, otherwise u have to change the order of the rules.